# Constraint error for UIScrollView with an empty UIStackView in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, interface-builder, uistackview

I'm following the "**Dynamic Stack View**" part of this [Stack View Apple tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/LayoutUsingStackViews.html), and I'm running into an constraint issue in Interface Builder if I leave the `UIStackView` (within the `UIScrollView`) empty, as opposed to putting a `UIButton` inside it.  I want my `UIViewController` to dynamically create all of the `arrangedSubviews`, so I don't want to leave a single `UIView` in there that I will just have to handle or delete programmatically.

I can ignore the error and it will still work as I want, with no runtime constraint errors.  However, I don't want to leave constraint issues within my xib/nib.

What's the cleanest way to satisfy Interface Builder?  If I add a concrete height constraint, then I have to create an outlet for it and delete it programatically.  That seems overly invasive and I'd rather leave as much Auto Layout in the xib/nib as possible.

[image: The Interface Builder overview]

[image: The constraint error]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It turns out that in order to satisfy Interface Builder, the `UIScrollView` needs to have a height for its contents, and it won't assume a height of `0`.  So since the `UIStackView` is the content view, it needs to have a height.  Even though at runtime it will have content, and thus a height, Interface Builder needs to have a fallback.  So therefore, set the **Intrinsic Size**.

It's at the bottom of *Size inspector*:

[image]

Change *Intrinsic Size* from *Default (System Defined)* to *Placeholder* and set the *Height* to whatever you want.  Something large enough to help while designing in Interface Builder is probably a good idea.  You can leave *Width* set to whatever, or check the *None* checkbox.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution here!